# Why doesn't Samba represent Linux symlinks as NTFS symlinks?

Tags: symlink, samba, smb

Samba is showing/representing symlinks as regular folders.  NTFS has symlink reparse points, and these can be represented via UNC - I tried sharing the Users directory in Windows and it showed the symlink as an actual NTFS symlink (`All Users`).  So why doesn't Samba use NTFS symlinks over UNC to represent Linux symlinks?  I think it would be much more accurate than representing them as the symlink target.

I have tried changing `follow symlinks` and `wide links` to "no" and "yes" but it doesn't change the representation of symlinks, just whether Samba allows you to navigate in to them.

Comment: Samba is far from a perfect implementation and the developers have openly commented on this fact.

Comment: Yeah but how hard is it to present symlinks as NTFS symlinks?

Comment: Because NTFS "symlinks" are basically garbage, a legacy from the bad old days when windows was a poorly written layer over a DOS shell. NTFS "symlinks" are basically files in their own right stating what to link to rather than a specific type of filesystem entry.

Comment: @Shadur I don't think you understand what NTFS symlinks are.  They're not `lnk` shortcut files, they're reparse points that are pretty much the same as Linux symlinks semantically.

Comment: For more on which, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/ .

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the min and max protocol options for Samba?  You need SMB 2.0 for symlinks as Windows interprets them (Samba doesn't expose symlinks over CIFS with the UNIX extensions for security reasons, not that Windows would even pay attention to them there).

Comment: I tried setting `server min protocol = SMB2_10` and `server max protocol = SMB2_10` and restarting, and still symlinks appear as regular folders.